# Java Spark DataFrameReader java.lang.NegativeArraySizeException

Tags: java, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

Learning Spark for java and trying to read in a `.csv` file as a `DataFrame` using the `DataFrameReader`, can't even get a super simple `.csv` file to work as I keep getting exception `java.lang.NegativeArraySizeException`.

Here is what I am doing:

```
public void test() {
    DataFrameReader dataFrameReader = new DataFrameReader(getSparkSession());

    StructType parentSchema = new StructType(new StructField[] {
            DataTypes.createStructField("NAME", DataTypes.StringType, false),
    });

    Dataset<Row> parents = dataFrameReader.schema(parentSchema).csv("/Users/mjsee/Downloads/test.csv");
    parents.show();
}
```

and here is how I am setting up my spark session

```
  sparkSession = SparkSession.builder()
                .appName(getApplicationName())
                .master("local[*]")
                .config("spark.driver.host", "localhost")
                .getOrCreate();
```

and here is my `tst.csv` file:

```
"JESSE"
```

and here is my output

```
java.lang.NegativeArraySizeException
    at com.univocity.parsers.common.input.DefaultCharAppender.<init>(DefaultCharAppender.java:39) ~[Univocity-Parsers-2.x.jar:?]
    at com.univocity.parsers.csv.CsvParserSettings.newCharAppender(CsvParserSettings.java:82) ~[Univocity-Parsers-2.x.jar:?]
    at com.univocity.parsers.common.ParserOutput.<init>(ParserOutput.java:93) ~[Univocity-Parsers-2.x.jar:?]
    at com.univocity.parsers.common.AbstractParser.<init>(AbstractParser.java:74) ~[Univocity-Parsers-2.x.jar:?]
    at com.univocity.parsers.csv.CsvParser.<init>(CsvParser.java:59) ~[Univocity-Parsers-2.x.jar:?]
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.csv.CsvReader.<init>(CSVParser.scala:49) ~[Spark-sql.jar:?]
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.csv.CSVFileFormat$$anonfun$buildReader$1.apply(CSVFileFormat.scala:158) ~[Spark-sql.jar:?]
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.csv.CSVFileFormat$$anonfun$buildReader$1.apply(CSVFileFormat.scala:146) ~[Spark-sql.jar:?]
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.FileFormat$$anon$1.apply(FileFormat.scala:138) ~[Spark-sql.jar:?]
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.FileFormat$$anon$1.apply(FileFormat.scala:122) ~[Spark-sql.jar:?]
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.FileScanRDD$$anon$1.nextIterator(FileScanRDD.scala:150) ~[Spark-sql.jar:?]
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.FileScanRDD$$anon$1.hasNext(FileScanRDD.scala:102) ~[Spark-sql.jar:?]
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.GeneratedClass$GeneratedIterator.processNext(Unknown Source) ~[?:?]
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.BufferedRowIterator.hasNext(BufferedRowIterator.java:43) ~[Spark-sql.jar:?]
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.WholeStageCodegenExec$$anonfun$8$$anon$1.hasNext(WholeStageCodegenExec.scala:377) ~[Spark-sql.jar:?]
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan$$anonfun$2.apply(SparkPlan.scala:231) ~[Spark-sql.jar:?]
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan$$anonfun$2.apply(SparkPlan.scala:225) ~[Spark-sql.jar:?]
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$mapPartitionsInternal$1$$anonfun$apply$25.apply(RDD.scala:826) ~[Spark-core.jar:?]
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$mapPartitionsInternal$1$$anonfun$apply$25.apply(RDD.scala:826) ~[Spark-core.jar:?]
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.compute(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:38) ~[Spark-core.jar:?]
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:323) ~[Spark-core.jar:?]
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:287) ~[Spark-core.jar:?]
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ResultTask.runTask(ResultTask.scala:87) ~[Spark-core.jar:?]
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:99) ~[Spark-core.jar:?]
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:282) [Spark-core.jar:?]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142) [?:1.8.0_131]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617) [?:1.8.0_131]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748) [?:1.8.0_131]
15:45:29.544 [task-result-getter-0] ERROR org.apache.spark.scheduler.TaskSetManager - Task 0 in stage 0.0 failed 1 times; aborting job

org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted due to stage failure: Task 0 in stage 0.0 failed 1 times, most recent failure: Lost task 0.0 in stage 0.0 (TID 0, localhost, executor driver): java.lang.NegativeArraySizeException
    at com.univocity.parsers.common.input.DefaultCharAppender.<init>(DefaultCharAppender.java:39)
    at com.univocity.parsers.csv.CsvParserSettings.newCharAppender(CsvParserSettings.java:82)
    at com.univocity.parsers.common.ParserOutput.<init>(ParserOutput.java:93)
    at com.univocity.parsers.common.AbstractParser.<init>(AbstractParser.java:74)
    at com.univocity.parsers.csv.CsvParser.<init>(CsvParser.java:59)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.csv.CsvReader.<init>(CSVParser.scala:49)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.csv.CSVFileFormat$$anonfun$buildReader$1.apply(CSVFileFormat.scala:158)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.csv.CSVFileFormat$$anonfun$buildReader$1.apply(CSVFileFormat.scala:146)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.FileFormat$$anon$1.apply(FileFormat.scala:138)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.FileFormat$$anon$1.apply(FileFormat.scala:122)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.FileScanRDD$$anon$1.nextIterator(FileScanRDD.scala:150)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.FileScanRDD$$anon$1.hasNext(FileScanRDD.scala:102)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.GeneratedClass$GeneratedIterator.processNext(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.BufferedRowIterator.hasNext(BufferedRowIterator.java:43)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.WholeStageCodegenExec$$anonfun$8$$anon$1.hasNext(WholeStageCodegenExec.scala:377)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan$$anonfun$2.apply(SparkPlan.scala:231)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan$$anonfun$2.apply(SparkPlan.scala:225)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$mapPartitionsInternal$1$$anonfun$apply$25.apply(RDD.scala:826)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$mapPartitionsInternal$1$$anonfun$apply$25.apply(RDD.scala:826)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.compute(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:38)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:323)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:287)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ResultTask.runTask(ResultTask.scala:87)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:99)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:282)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)

Driver stacktrace:

    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.org$apache$spark$scheduler$DAGScheduler$$failJobAndIndependentStages(DAGScheduler.scala:1435)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$abortStage$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:1423)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$abortStage$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:1422)
    at scala.collection.mutable.ResizableArray$class.foreach(ResizableArray.scala:59)
    at scala.collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer.foreach(ArrayBuffer.scala:48)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.abortStage(DAGScheduler.scala:1422)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$handleTaskSetFailed$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:802)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$handleTaskSetFailed$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:802)
    at scala.Option.foreach(Option.scala:257)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.handleTaskSetFailed(DAGScheduler.scala:802)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.doOnReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:1650)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.onReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:1605)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.onReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:1594)
    at org.apache.spark.util.EventLoop$$anon$1.run(EventLoop.scala:48)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.runJob(DAGScheduler.scala:628)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:1918)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:1931)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:1944)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan.executeTake(SparkPlan.scala:333)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.CollectLimitExec.executeCollect(limit.scala:38)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset$$anonfun$org$apache$spark$sql$Dataset$$execute$1$1.apply(Dataset.scala:2371)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.withNewExecutionId(SQLExecution.scala:57)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.withNewExecutionId(Dataset.scala:2765)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.org$apache$spark$sql$Dataset$$execute$1(Dataset.scala:2370)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.org$apache$spark$sql$Dataset$$collect(Dataset.scala:2377)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset$$anonfun$head$1.apply(Dataset.scala:2113)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset$$anonfun$head$1.apply(Dataset.scala:2112)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.withTypedCallback(Dataset.scala:2795)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.head(Dataset.scala:2112)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.take(Dataset.scala:2327)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.showString(Dataset.scala:248)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.show(Dataset.scala:636)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.show(Dataset.scala:595)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.show(Dataset.scala:604)
    at ModelProcessingTest.testSTUFF(ModelProcessingTest.java:86)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:50)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:47)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.InvokeMethod.evaluate(InvokeMethod.java:17)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunBefores.evaluate(RunBefores.java:26)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunAfters.evaluate(RunAfters.java:27)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:325)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:78)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:57)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)
    at org.mockito.internal.runners.JUnit45AndHigherRunnerImpl.run(Unknown Source)
    at org.mockito.runners.MockitoJUnitRunner.run(Unknown Source)
    at org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.run(JUnitCore.java:137)
    at com.intellij.junit4.JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.startRunnerWithArgs(JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.java:68)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.IdeaTestRunner$Repeater.startRunnerWithArgs(IdeaTestRunner.java:51)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.prepareStreamsAndStart(JUnitStarter.java:237)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.main(JUnitStarter.java:70)
Caused by: java.lang.NegativeArraySizeException
    at com.univocity.parsers.common.input.DefaultCharAppender.<init>(DefaultCharAppender.java:39)
    at com.univocity.parsers.csv.CsvParserSettings.newCharAppender(CsvParserSettings.java:82)
    at com.univocity.parsers.common.ParserOutput.<init>(ParserOutput.java:93)
    at com.univocity.parsers.common.AbstractParser.<init>(AbstractParser.java:74)
    at com.univocity.parsers.csv.CsvParser.<init>(CsvParser.java:59)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.csv.CsvReader.<init>(CSVParser.scala:49)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.csv.CSVFileFormat$$anonfun$buildReader$1.apply(CSVFileFormat.scala:158)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.csv.CSVFileFormat$$anonfun$buildReader$1.apply(CSVFileFormat.scala:146)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.FileFormat$$anon$1.apply(FileFormat.scala:138)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.FileFormat$$anon$1.apply(FileFormat.scala:122)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.FileScanRDD$$anon$1.nextIterator(FileScanRDD.scala:150)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.FileScanRDD$$anon$1.hasNext(FileScanRDD.scala:102)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.GeneratedClass$GeneratedIterator.processNext(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.BufferedRowIterator.hasNext(BufferedRowIterator.java:43)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.WholeStageCodegenExec$$anonfun$8$$anon$1.hasNext(WholeStageCodegenExec.scala:377)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan$$anonfun$2.apply(SparkPlan.scala:231)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan$$anonfun$2.apply(SparkPlan.scala:225)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$mapPartitionsInternal$1$$anonfun$apply$25.apply(RDD.scala:826)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$mapPartitionsInternal$1$$anonfun$apply$25.apply(RDD.scala:826)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.compute(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:38)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:323)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:287)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ResultTask.runTask(ResultTask.scala:87)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:99)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:282)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

Comment: Is `/Users/mjsee/Downloads/test.csv` a hdfs path, or a path on your edge node, or a path on your local machine?

Comment: Path on my localhost

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Author of the [univocity-parsers](http://www.univocity.com/pages/parsers-tutorial) library here. This is happening because internally spark is setting the maximum value length to `-1` (meaning no limit). This was introduced in univocity-parsers versions 2.2.0 onward.

Just make sure this library version is greater than 2.2.0 and you should be fine, as the older versions don't support setting the `maxCharsPerColumn` property to `-1`.

If you have multiple versions of that library in your classpath, get rid of the older ones. Ideally you'd want to update to the latest version (currently 2.4.1.) and use only that. It should work just fine as we make sure any changes made to the library are backward compatible.

Answer (score 0):

May be you have a comma after `createStructField` in your parentschema that is causing the issue ?

```
StructType parentSchema = new StructType(new StructField[] {
            DataTypes.createStructField("NAME", DataTypes.StringType, false)
    });
```

**Person ( csv under resources)**
Jagan,Pantula,37,Singapore
Neeraja,Pantula,32,Singapore
Rama,Pantula,34,India
Rajya,Akundi,32,India
Viswanath,Pantula,42,India

**Code**

```
 SparkSession session = getSession();    
 DataFrameReader reader = new DataFrameReader(session);   
 StructType parentSchema = new StructType(new StructField[] {
    DataTypes.createStructField("FirstName", DataTypes.StringType, false),
    DataTypes.createStructField("LastName", DataTypes.StringType, false),
    DataTypes.createStructField("Age", DataTypes.IntegerType, false),
    DataTypes.createStructField("Country", DataTypes.StringType, false)
 });

 String path = getClass().getClassLoader()
                         .getResource("Person")
                         .getPath()
                         .substring(1);
 reader.schema(parentSchema).csv(path).show();
```

**Output**

```
+---------+--------+---+---------+
|FirstName|LastName|Age|  Country|
+---------+--------+---+---------+
|    Jagan| Pantula| 37|Singapore|
|  Neeraja| Pantula| 32|Singapore|
|     Rama| Pantula| 34|    India|
|    Rajya|  Akundi| 32|    India|
|Viswanath| Pantula| 42|    India|
+---------+--------+---+---------+
```